# knockout if binding doesn't work with <select>

Tags: knockout.js

Why does this work:

```
<!-- ko if: show -->
    <select data-bind="options: categories, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select', value: selected_category"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and this doesn't:

```
<select data-bind="if: show, options: categories, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: 'Select', value: selected_category"></select>
```

in another words why cannot show boolean be used inside data-bind with 'if'?

Comment: The resulting error summarizes the issue : *Multiple bindings (if and options) are trying to control descendant bindings of the **same element**. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element.* (my emphasis) The containerless syntax works because "*the <!-- ko --> and <!-- /ko --> comments act as start/end markers, defining a “virtual element” that contains the markup inside*", as mentioned near the end of the [if binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) documentation.

Comment: Origineil: That's not entirely true, if you just have an if binding on a select it still renders the select.

Comment: "*The if binding, however, physically adds or removes the contained markup in your DOM, and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true.*" If we assume "contained" to mean child elements, then indeed that is how it is designed to work.

Comment: contained markup = child elements, not the element itself. They should make that clear in the docs.

Comment: Yea I had to read it several times before I clued in on the intent of the statement.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks! I guess the reason for it to apply only to child elements is for dynamic add/remove: 'the markup within your if block can be added or removed dynamically as the result of the expression changes'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `visible` binding instead to hide the select.

As for your larger question, the `if` binding actually physically removes all the *child* DOM of the element bound with if and stores it in a node cache for later retrieval. This is to prevent any further binding within those elements which might affect other document elements.

For example, in the snippet below, if you open your browser's element inspector and push the toggle button repeatedly, you'll see the browser injecting and removing the innerText of the `span`.

```js
var vm = {
  show: ko.observable(true),
  toggle: function() {
    this.show(!this.show());
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span data-bind='if:show'>Show Me</span>
<input type='button' data-bind='click: toggle' value='Toggle' />
```

And per [Knockout's if binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html):

> Correspondingly, the markup **within** your if block can be added or
>   removed dynamically as the result of the expression changes. data-bind
>   attributes will be applied to a new copy of the contained markup
>   whenever it is re-added.

Comment: Yep, `visible` is a workaround with a consequence of `<select>` still being rendered. It's a workaround but not an answer.